# Java = Return Object list/array vs. Result-Object (the same with method parameters)

Tags: java, oop

This might seem to be a strange question: I am struggling to decide whether it is a good practice and "efficient" to work with "Typed Objects" on a very granular level.

```
public Object[] doSomething() {
    Object[] resultList = new Object[] {new Foo(), new Bar()};
    return resultList;
}
```

versus

```
public Result doSomething() {
    Result result = new Result();
    result.foo = new Foo();
    result.bar = new Bar();
    return result;
}

public class Result{
    Foo foo;
    Bar bar;
}
```

My question is concrete as follows:

1. In terms of CPU Cycles (as a relative figure), how much does the second approach consume more resources. (like 100% more)
2. The same question in regard to memory consumption

NB (these two are questions to understand it more, its not about premature optimization)

3. In terms of "good design practice". Do you think version 1 is an absolute No-Go or do you rather think it actually does not matter...Or would you propose never returning "object Arrays" (((in an object oriented programming language)))...

This is something, I am always wondering if I should create dedicated Objects for everything (for passing values) or I should rather use generic objects (and common method parameters...)

The question also applies to

```
public doSomething(Query query )
```

versus

```
public doSomething(Foo foo, Bar bar, Aaaa, a, Bbbbb)
```

thanks

Markus

Comment: 3). Correct. Case 1 is a no go. The most important thing when it comes to developing code is to make the code maintainable, and case 1 is hard to maintain.

Comment: Personally, I always prefer the 2nd options. For code readability if not for anything else.

Comment: Option 2) will be slightly faster due to elimination of casts when Results are used, and also probably save 4-8 bytes per call depending on the JVM implementation (since Result will be smaller than an Object[2])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd have to do an experiment to really know, but I'd guess that the object array would not be significantly faster. It might even be slower. After all, in either case you have to create an object: either the array object or the Result object. With the Result object you have to read the class definition from disk the first time you use it, and the class definition has to float around in memory, so there'd be some extra cost there. But with the array object you have to do casts when you pull the data out, and the JVM has to do bounds checkings on the array (What happens if the caller tries to retrieve resultList[12]?), which also involves extra work. My guess is that if you do it only once or twice, the array would be faster (because of the class load time), but if you do it many times, the dedicated object would be faster (because of the cast and array access time). But I admit I'm just guessing.

In any case, even if the array does have a slight performance edge, the loss in readability and maintainability of the code almost surely isn't worth it.

The absolute worst thing that can happen is if values you're returning in the array are of the same class but have different semantic meanings. Like suppose you did this:

```
public Object[] getCustomerData(int customerid)
{
  String customerName=... however you get it ...
  BigDecimal currentDue=...
  BigDecimal pastDue=...
  return new Object[] {customerName, pastDue, currentDue};
}
... meanwhile, back at the ranch ...
Object[] customerData=getCustomerData(customerid);
BigDecimal pastDue=(BigDecimal)customerData[2];
if (pastDue>0)
  sendNastyCollectionLetter();
```

Do you see the error? I retrieve entry #2 as pastDue when it's supposed to be #1. You could easily imagine this happenning if a programmer in a moment of thoughtlessness counted the fields starting from one instead of zero. Or in a long list if he miscounted and said #14 when it's really #15. As both have the same data type, this will compile and run just fine. But we'll be sending inappropriate collection letters to customers who are not over due. This would be very bad for customer relations.

Okay, maybe this is a bad example -- I just pulled it off the top of my head -- because we would be likely to catch that in testing. But what if the values we switched were rarely used, so that no one thought to include a test scenario for them. Or their effect was subtle, so that an error might slip through testing. For that matter, maybe you wouldn't catch this one in testing if you were rushing a change through, or if the tester slipped up, etc etc.

Answer (score 6):

> 3.) In terms of "good design pratice". Do you think version 1 is an absolute No-Go or do you rather think it actually does not matter...Or would you propose never returnung "object Arrays" (((in an object oriented programming langauge/regarding encapsulation ...)))...

Version 1 is **absolutely** a no-go. It's almost completely untyped. The caller has to know the actual types and where they are in the array, and cast appropriately. You lose any useful compile-time type checking, and the code itself is **significantly** less clear.

I would never return an `Object[]` unless the values it contained were constructed with `new Object()`.

Comment: The only time I return an Object[] is if the return really is a set of objects that could be of different types, and the position in the array has no semantic significance. That is, the caller does not assume that #1 is userid and #2 is the password or anything like that. Either the array is just "here's all the objects that fit whatever it is you're looking for", or they're arranged in some order, like alphabetical order or chronological order.

Comment: Returning a heterogeneous `Object[]` still requires the caller to cast elements of the array. I just don't see a good reason to do this over defining a proper class, or using a `Map`, or a `List<something more specific than Object>`.

Comment: If the objects produced are, or can be made to be, all subtypes of the same class, absolutely. It's much better to return a MyHoozit[] than an Object[]. I was thinking of cases where you didn't write the classes being produced. Like, I was just working on a generic function that builds a web page from a variety of form objects, plain-text strings, etc. I need to put them in a List before I convert them to Strings because some of the objects can be updated after the list is built. I don't see how to make the List anything but List<Object> --much as it pains me.

Comment: Why did you need to use a `List` at all? Why not create a proper `class` to hold the values?

Comment: Hmm, I think we have a communication breakdown. I have a number of objects with no semantic distinction, just a group of things that are to be displayed on the screen in order. That's what a List is for: to hold a "list". If I created my own class, it would have to be a re-implementation of List.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe that defining a `Result` class and returning that consumes any more resources at run time than constructing an `Object[]`. (Granted, there's a miniscule cost for storing and loading the class definition.) Do you have data that indicate otherwise?

Returning an untyped object array is poor practice for various reasons, among which are:

1. It's prone to error.
2. It's harder to maintain.
3. Casting back to the "real" type is not free, either.

Regarding your other query:

```
public doSomething(Query query)
```

versus

```
public doSomething(Foo foo, Bar bar)
```

This is less clear-cut. If packaging up a `Foo` and a `Bar` into a `Query` object makes sense in the problem domain, then I would definitely do it. If it's just a packaging up for the sake of minimizing the number of arguments (that is, there's no "query object" concept in your problem domain), then I would probably not do it. If it's a question of run-time performance, then the answer is (as always) to profile.

Comment: +1. In fact, a Result is probably less overhead than an Object[2] in most current JVM implementations, since an array contains an extra field for the array length in addition to the normal object header.